# New Line Character not Recognized in ASP .Net Text Box

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to display the data with new line in text box. I am saving the comment in DB and then displaying the data on the UI.

The below is the .aspx code :-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="comment" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"
            Rows="5" Columns="100" CssClass="multiline-text"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is my DB Comment :-

```
This is test Comment./r/n Please do some reply on this.
```

How its showing on UI :-

```
This is test Comment./r/n Please do some reply on this.
```

Then I updated DB Comment :-

```
This is test Comment.<br /> Please do some reply on this.
```

How its showing on UI :-

```
This is test Comment.<br /> Please do some reply on this.
```

What I can change in asp .net file or in DB so that the data displays with new line in text box.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to mention here:

1. You are actually using wrong [escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences), it should be `\r\n` (backslash instead of slash)
2. If you get this data from somewhere else (e.g. the database), it probably would be correctly escaped
   Consider check the string while debugging to verify what's actually coming from your source
3. When you've verified the text, you can then replace the necessary characters by correct escape characters:
   Assuming this is coming as text in a variable `myText`:
   `This is test Comment.\r\n Please do some reply on this.`
   then you can think of `This is test Comment.\\r\\n Please do some reply on this.`
   and you can do the following:

```
comment.Text = myText.Replace("\\r\\n", "\n"); // replace text "\r\n" by a new line escape sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Wrap** Property which display ASP.Net TextBox with multiline property to automatically continues on next line when it reaches the end.

`<asp:TextBox ID="comment" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Wrap="true" Rows="5" Columns="100" CssClass="multiline-text"></asp:TextBox>`

Additionally, you can add this line in your css class to make sure proper lines break at `<br>` and preserve white space.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```